# Replace an existing GridFS file with new content using Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, gridfs

I have some data in MongoDB GridFS. I am using the Spring Data `GridFsOperations` class to do my GridFS read/writes.

I have a requirement to replace the content of an existing GridFS file i.e. the `_id` and `filename` should stay the same, but the file content should be updated.

Spring Data `[GridFsOperations]` ([API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/api/)) primarily allows `find`, which returns a Mongo `GridFSDBFile`, and `store`. `GridFSDBFile` ([API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSDBFile.html)) does not allow updating content. The `store` method could in theory be used if the file was deleted first, and then stored with the same `_id` as the previous file. However `store` does not allow specifying the `_id` field.

The only solution I have found so far is to use the Mongo API directly to delete the existing file, and store a new one with the same `_id`. Answers to this effect are not useful: the question is specific to Spring Data MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there's no API exposed yet is that there's no support for that on the MongoDB GridFS. You essentially work around this issue implementing a pattern like described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/-xuQ-dra5Ac). But as this boils down to a non-atomic operation we decided to not expose it as operation in the first place.

In case you thing there's a reliable implementation of this pattern (plus the appropriate handling of error cases) feel free to open ticket in our [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO) to discuss options.

Comment: Yup, that is essentially what I did using the Mongo API. 

I would say a reasonable first step for Spring Data would to allow the `store` method to take a pre-existing value of _id, so that users can at least implement this two-step pattern in their own code via the Spring Data API. As it stands now, I had to use reflection to get the private `GridFS` object from `GridFsOperations`, and then use that directly to create the new file.